# Load audio from another domain

Tags: javascript, audio

Im trying to create some text to speech using jTalk.

getting the request without a problem but, when trying to access the audio file with howl i get.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Is there any solution to load audio from external server?

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this problem use the JSONP wrapper instead of just JSON.

End your json call with callback=? to ensure it has a JSONP callback.

Comment: I use jsonp and get the write response from server including the path to the audio. The problem is loading the audio through howlerjs from external server.

I think the only solution is to add the address to audio element, but howler doesn't accept audio elements as source, just urls